# Open Lightbox in top frame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, lightbox

I'm including a page on my site with an iframe. The page in the iframe has the functionality to open a lightbox, which now of course opens in the iframe itself.

Is there a possibility that the iframe content opens the lightbox on the top frame? (On the page that includes this iframe)

Answer (score 0):

if it's opening via javascript, use

```
window.top.location = "http://destination-url.com";
```

if it's a anchor link, then add

```
target="_top":
```

Comment: Light box is a javascript modal popup and it cannot be loaded like this.